# How to Detect that user have selected date from html input date

Tags: php, html, date

i am new to html and p-h-p. what i am looking for is that i have provided user an input date calendar through html date input method.
Now how can i detect that user have provided date or not ... if he didn't selected date from calendar he should be get an alert to please provide date... 
the problem i'm facing is if user is not selecting a date so the value of "date-from" which is the "value" of input date is setting to default date automatically. 
by default i mean least date.
i should be very much thankful if anyone can help ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what (code, markup, etc.) you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: Providing a little context is extremely helpful in finding the best solution to your problem. Also code samples are very useful. Are the users required to select dates other than the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't we just use the HTML5 required?

```
<input type="date" name="date" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you used JavaScript for this purpose instead. By doing that you will be able to keep it client sided and the user don't have to refresh the page to validate.

Pls have a look at "onblur" event or just "onsubmit" in JavaScript